# Get thumbnail of a photo with facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am getting an image from the facebook graph api and this works fine:

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture?access_token=' + accessToken;
```

However I want to get a thumbnail of this image instead.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `/picture?type=square&access_token=' + accessToken;` or the `width` and `height` parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `/picture` add `?type=thumbnail` to the url to obtain a 75px wide version of the image.